# Jquery-Image-gallery- >>Initially showing 4images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating n image gallery.

Initially I need to show 4 images. and on click of next 4images/video should display.

I am able to show one image at a time.

I need help

this is what i have tried
http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/43/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)**: select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

for example

```
$('.thumb-layout:gt(4)').hide();
```

hide all `$('.thumb-layout')` with index greater than `4`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/44/)

```
$('p:gt('+i+'):lt('+inRow+')').show()
```

Show `inRow` elements with index greater than `i`

---

modified in accordance to the comment:
http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/50/

Comment: Can you please send me the same of my structure please. your demo is working fine. But please send me the structure and data that I am using. please brother

Comment: I changed its working but a small issue as I am having only 4 solutions and I am clicking on next button then why the empty row is showing, if again am clicking on next then the normal 4 solutions are coming: Please check it out once. that emptu row should not come. http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/49/

Comment: Index starts at 0. just fix this row `$('.thumb-layout:gt('+(i-1)+'):lt('+inRow+')').show()`